# State isn't updating should be for Minecraft scoreboard

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have a functional interface that returns a String when executed. In this functional interface, I pass through an instance of a class, that upon calling, should reference that instance and get the a current value within that class (this value is updated elsewhere). So this value changes, and it should also update each time I execute my functional interface, as it references this class and variable.

There is a fair amount of code, so for simplicity sake...

My LineExecution interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface LineExecution {

    String execute(Player p);

}
```

My Scoreboard class:
https://pastebin.com/0aHa81eA

I update the `state#getReferencedTime` value here:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Logger.debug("setting referenced time");
    Logger.debug("EXECUTIONA: " + execution.execute(a.getPlayers().stream().findFirst().orElse(null).getPlayer()));
    state.setReferencedTime(i);
    Logger.debug("getting referenced time: " + state.getReferencedTime());
    a.getPlayers().forEach(p -> {
        Logger.debug("updating... state: " + state.getReferencedTime());
        GameBoard g = state.getGameBoard(p.getPlayer());
        g.update(p.getPlayer());
    });
    i--;
}
```

This is what is printed in console:
https://pastebin.com/bUC5sBQj

And this is my 'GameBoard' class:

```
public class GameBoard extends Scoreboard {

    public GameBoard(GameBoardType type, GameStateManager state) {
        super(type.getTitle());

        addLine(p -> {
            return "stateRef: " + state.getReferencedTime();
        }, Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer("Realmm").getPlayer());
    }

}
```

So, I just want to be able to update `state.getReferencedTime`, which I do in the `run()`, and then, when I execute that functional interface again by calling `GameBoard#update(Player)` it should show `9`, counting down until `0`. But it's just always showing `10`, no matter if I change the value or not.